# Why do a line and polygon still intersect after using st_difference() in R?

Tags: r, sf, linestring, differences, st-difference

I have a line that intersects a polygon, and I would like to get only the portion of the line that does **not** intersect the polygon. Using `sf::st_difference()` does indeed trim the line, but the result still intersects with the polygon (see reprex below). This suggests to me that `st_difference()` does not fully clip the line, which conflicts with my understanding of how the function should work.

I would like to learn two things: (1) Why does the line result of `st_difference()` still intersect with the original polygon that was used in the clipping operation? (2) How can I clip the line so that the result does not intersect with the polygon?

```
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

## recreate objects

line <- structure(list(structure(list(structure(c(-80.2691, -80.26838, -80.26564, -80.26508, -80.26405, -80.26098, -4.40096, -4.40064, -4.39997, -4.39876, -4.39795, -4.39754), dim = c(6L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "MULTILINESTRING", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_MULTILINESTRING", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -80.2691, ymin = -4.40096, xmax = -80.26098, ymax = -4.39754), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "WGS 84", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    ENSEMBLE[\"World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble\",\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)\"],\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Horizontal component of 3D system.\"],\n        AREA[\"World.\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)

polygon <- structure(list(structure(list(list(structure(c(-79.8168422, -79.8180025, -79.8316819, -79.8597269, -79.8777909, -79.8841729, -79.8922269, -79.9203459, -79.9411179, -79.9441729, -79.9563179, -80.0211179, -80.1427909, -80.2699359, -80.2913999, -80.3236269, -80.3404269, -80.2591729, -80.2349999, -80.2127819, -80.2061179, -80.2077819, -80.2113999, -80.1766729, -80.1533359, -80.1752909, -80.2922359, -80.3189639, -80.3456999, -80.3891729, -80.4202909, -80.4654269, -80.5014499, -80.4836089, -80.4807639, -80.4645819, -80.4455639, -80.4105639, -80.3829269, -80.3402819, -80.3829269, -80.3991729, -80.4311179, -80.4799999, -80.4812549, -80.4637639, -80.4097269, -80.3905639, -80.3586179, -80.3341729, -80.2622179, -80.2263909, -80.1865359, -80.1745819, -80.1345999, -80.0779269, -80.0587639, -80.0251459, -79.9977909, -79.8156359, -79.7837639, -79.7052819, -79.6680639, -79.6431999, -79.6213909, -79.5391729, -79.5197269, -79.5152819, -79.4516729, -79.4450359, -79.3655729, -79.2857089, -79.2319179, -79.2036089, -79.1836269, -79.1002729, -79.0632089, -79.0366639, -79.0113999, -78.9286179, -78.9184819, -78.9183999, -78.9061089, -78.8761089, -78.8593089, -78.8237639, -78.7908459, -78.7672269, -78.7162544, -78.6836179, -78.6668089, -78.6502819, -78.6528459, -78.6701459, -78.6724999, -78.6657729, -78.6415359, -78.5636089, -78.5580639, -78.5555549, -78.5554269, -78.5536179, -78.5408459, -78.5316819, -78.4666729, -78.4175819, -78.3994549, -78.3886269, -78.3725089, -78.3670909, -78.3706999, -78.3679179, -78.3522359, -78.3461179, -78.3294549, -78.3013999, -78.2794459, -78.2613999, -78.2529269, -78.2513959, -78.1813999, -78.1705639, -78.1811909, -78.2034729, -78.2157089, -78.2004269, -78.1758459, -78.1413999, -78.1163909, -78.0672269, -78.0344549, -77.9253819, -77.8595909, -77.8023459, -77.4397269, -77.2241639, -77.0433359, -76.9044459, -76.6606269, -76.4038999, -76.0741729, -75.9775089, -75.7813999, -75.7197269, -75.6272819, -75.5881819, -75.5639459, -75.5536179, -75.4836089, -75.4616729, -75.4441729, -75.4319459, -75.4022359, -75.3769549, -75.3595909, -75.3304269, -75.2168459, -75.2633359, -75.2927819, -75.2736477, -75.2490269, -75.2443819, -75.2625089, -75.3397999, -75.3638909, -75.3894549, -75.4133459, -75.4344459, -75.4486179, -75.4591639, -75.4647359, -75.4811179, -75.5711909, -75.6244999, -75.6158179, -75.5190269, -75.4798729, -75.4250089, -75.3497269, -75.3052819, -75.2858459, -75.3000089, -75.3255639, -75.3497269, -75.3990359, -75.4344459, -75.5188909, -75.5754269, -75.6940359, -75.7275089, -75.7608459, -75.9127819, -75.9802819, -76.0248729, -76.0401179, -76.1452819, -76.2430549, -76.250742, -76.2716794, -76.2992337, -76.3249095, -76.3486374, -76.3703531, -76.3899978, -76.4075185, -76.4228679, -76.4360044, -76.4468928, -76.4555036, -76.4618138, -76.4704333, -76.4744387, -76.4761398, -76.475532, -76.4726168, -76.4674018, -76.459901, -76.4501342, -76.4381276, -76.423913, -76.4075286, -76.389018, -76.3684307, -76.345822, -76.3212523, -76.2947876, -76.2664989, -76.2364622, -76.2182656, -76.2219404, -76.2328932, -76.2626053, -76.2748923, -76.2922977, -76.29379, -76.315034, -76.3423964, -76.4047093, -76.4651332, -76.6596178, -76.6970894, -76.9500581, -77.093963, -77.202721, -77.3409629, -77.5207244, -77.7348532, 
                                                          -78.0963397, -78.1027825, -78.159912, -78.2026757, -78.2444277, 
                                                          -78.2850461, -78.3244122, -78.3624112, -78.3989323, -78.433869, 
                                                          -78.4994445, -78.5265842, -78.5525608, -78.5773242, -78.686019, 
                                                          -78.7118364, -78.7360682, -78.7586583, -78.76103, -78.7780136, 
                                                          -78.8156081, -78.8518481, -78.8866333, -78.9198677, -78.9514595, 
                                                          -78.9813212, -78.9979272, -79.0248762, -79.0500889, -79.0735012, 
                                                          -79.0950535, -79.114691, -79.1323639, -79.1480272, -79.161641, 
                                                          -79.1731707, -79.179272, -79.1839991, -79.1996432, -79.2085167, 
                                                          -79.2149707, -79.2177508, -79.2188052, -79.221117, -79.2484021, 
                                                          -79.2733928, -79.2960094, -79.31618, -79.3253181, -79.3301627, 
                                                          -79.339653, -79.3538128, -79.3539569, -79.3568163, -79.3621098, 
                                                          -79.3688187, -79.3763567, -79.3987076, -79.4110177, -79.4353213, 
                                                          -79.4475902, -79.4619701, -79.4784232, -79.4969065, -79.5173713, 
                                                          -79.5397641, -79.564026, -79.5900936, -79.6178984, -79.6473677, 
                                                          -79.6784243, -79.710987, -79.7449707, -79.7802865, -79.8168422, 
                                                          -2.7647382, -2.7641781, -2.8030549, -2.9127819, -3.0186089, -3.0386089, 
                                                          -3.0588909, -3.0893729, -3.1497179, -3.1818089, -3.2077819, -3.2616639, 
                                                          -3.3347179, -3.3386089, -3.3283359, -3.3597179, -3.3805179, -3.4174269, 
                                                          -3.4972179, -3.5958359, -3.6366639, -3.7172179, -3.7391639, -3.8591639, 
                                                          -3.8842269, -3.9030549, -3.9961089, -4.0116639, -3.9982639, -3.9790269, 
                                                          -3.9780549, -3.9852819, -4.0528139, -4.1144459, -4.1741639, -4.2074999, 
                                                          -4.2211819, -4.2098639, -4.1966639, -4.1995179, -4.2634729, -4.2818089, 
                                                          -4.3155549, -4.3884729, -4.4164549, -4.4418089, -4.4716639, -4.4786089, 
                                                          -4.4655549, -4.4524999, -4.3974999, -4.3644459, -4.3212549, -4.2985459, 
                                                          -4.2844909, -4.3001359, -4.3195819, -4.3549999, -4.3730549, -4.4788179, 
                                                          -4.4819459, -4.4570819, -4.4343089, -4.4354179, -4.4474999, -4.5208359, 
                                                          -4.5811819, -4.6204179, -4.7663909, -4.7973999, -4.8861089, -4.9645819, 
                                                          -4.9638549, -4.9624999, -4.9638909, -4.9750549, -5.0003089, -4.9955549, 
                                                          -4.9722179, -4.8683359, -4.7826359, -4.7410459, -4.7166639, -4.6772179, 
                                                          -4.6615269, -4.6359729, -4.6141639, -4.6038909, -4.5868409, -4.5744459, 
                                                          -4.5548639, -4.4736089, -4.4176359, -4.3651359, -4.3402819, -4.3038819, 
                                                          -4.2784729, -4.0955549, -4.0730549, -4.0469459, -4.0101359, -3.9786089, 
                                                          -3.9319459, -3.9127819, -3.8324999, -3.7811909, -3.7461089, -3.7113909, 
                                                          -3.6338909, -3.5728459, -3.5397179, -3.5183359, -3.4566639, -3.4349999, 
                                                          -3.4172179, -3.4077819, -3.4099999, -3.4247179, -3.4518089, -3.5184049, 
                                                          -3.4722179, -3.4519459, -3.4131269, -3.3924269, -3.3605549, -3.3343089, 
                                                          -3.3141639, -3.2941639, -3.2759729, -3.2152819, -3.1561819, -3.0399639, 
                                                          -2.9858359, -2.9657454, -2.8413909, -2.7672179, -2.7047179, -2.6566639, 
                                                          -2.5721359, -2.3802819, -2.1311089, -2.0163909, -1.7819459, -1.7080549, 
                                                          -1.5963729, -1.5557089, -1.5399549, -1.5138909, -1.2419459, -1.1536089, 
                                                          -1.0855549, -1.0380549, -0.9227819, -0.9508359, -0.9677819, -0.9797179, 
                                                          -0.9693639, -0.8147179, -0.7305549, -0.6496429, -0.6295819, -0.5609729, 
                                                          -0.5230549, -0.4646549, -0.4666639, -0.4469459, -0.4195819, -0.3841639, 
                                                          -0.3463179, -0.2949999, -0.2736089, -0.2323639, -0.1801359, -0.1720269, 
                                                          -0.1065179, -0.1168729, -0.1437549, -0.1643089, -0.1512549, -0.1347179, 
                                                          -0.1197179, -0.1022179, -0.0883359, -0.0783359, -0.0720819, -0.0594459, 
                                                          -0.0080549, 0.0318091, 0.0430541, 0.0355541, 0.0468091, 0.1633361, 
                                                          0.2563911, 0.3201271, 0.3376361, 0.3708361, 0.3955541, 0.3953964, 
                                                          0.374196, 0.3431414, 0.310846, 0.2773989, 0.2428925, 0.2074218, 
                                                          0.1710849, 0.133982, 0.0962154, 0.0578894, 0.0191096, -0.0200167, 
                                                          -0.0855076, -0.1246664, -0.1639544, -0.2032645, -0.2424893, -0.2815216, 
                                                          -0.320255, -0.3585835, -0.3964027, -0.4336091, -0.4701013, -0.5057795, 
                                                          -0.5405464, -0.5743071, -0.6069692, -0.6384437, -0.6686446, -0.6974894, 
                                                          -0.7132208, -0.7237151, -0.7619125, -0.8778439, -0.9258406, -0.9938945, 
                                                          -0.9998321, -1.0858393, -1.1929751, -1.2685888, -1.3413124, -1.5748461, 
                                                          -1.6195233, -1.8113309, -1.9192673, -1.9570465, -2.0049735, -2.0672304, 
                                                          -2.141057, -2.2652673, -2.2675068, -2.2875966, -2.3038173, -2.3220448, 
                                                          -2.3422255, -2.3643, -2.3882035, -2.4138654, -2.4412104, -2.4953367, 
                                                          -2.5187205, -2.5431154, -2.568474, -2.6846906, -2.7136497, -2.7436481, 
                                                          -2.7746154, -2.7782326, -2.7873455, -2.8099456, -2.8342393, -2.8601589, 
                                                          -2.8876319, -2.916582, -2.9469282, -2.9647065, -2.9950523, -3.0265272, 
                                                          -3.0590506, -3.0925389, -3.1269061, -3.1620642, -3.1979227, -3.2343898, 
                                                          -3.2713717, -3.2930335, -3.3107006, -3.372372, -3.4122505, -3.4524357, 
                                                          -3.4738162, -3.4843418, -3.4872041, -3.5230371, -3.560122, -3.5983397, 
                                                          -3.6375675, -3.6567298, -3.6677068, -3.6386152, -3.6026699, -3.5888867, 
                                                          -3.5488507, -3.5090655, -3.4682384, -3.429628, -3.3310105, -3.2846153, 
                                                          -3.2048285, -3.1683749, -3.1325667, -3.0974969, -3.0632562, -3.0299335, 
                                                          -2.997615, -2.9663846, -2.9363231, -2.9075086, -2.8800156, -2.8539155, 
                                                          -2.8292758, -2.8061604, -2.7846293, -2.7647382), dim = c(322L, 
                                                                                                                   2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_MULTIPOLYGON", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -80.5014499, ymin = -5.0003089, xmax = -75.2168459, ymax = 0.3955541), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "WGS 84", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    ENSEMBLE[\"World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble\",\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)\"],\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Horizontal component of 3D system.\"],\n        AREA[\"World.\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)

## confirm that objects intersect
st_intersects(line, polygon, sparse = F) 
#>      [,1]
#> [1,] TRUE

## apply st_difference 
line_diff <- st_difference(line, polygon)

## result is a shortened version of the line, but the result still intersects with the original polygon
st_length(line)
#> 1037.197 [m]
st_length(line_diff) # shorter 
#> 174.8891 [m]
st_intersects(line_diff, polygon, sparse = F)
#>      [,1]
#> [1,] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spatial objects can be considered as three sets of points in the continuum - the interior, the boundary, and the exterior. The various spatial operations work on those sets.

The `difference` operator subtracts the interior of the polygon from the line. The boundary of the polygon is not part of the interior. The point that the line and the polygon share becomes the new boundary (end point) of the line.

Then the `st_intersects` predicate is a test for intersection of interior and boundary sets. Your polygon and `line_diff` share a point on their boundaries, and so they "intersect", as you have discovered.

The polygon and the line feature should fail the `st_crosses` test which relates to the interiors: "a crosses b: they have some but not all interior points in common". And indeed they do:

```
> st_crosses(polygon, line)
although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_crosses assumes that they are
planar
Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 1, where the predicate
was `crosses'
 1: 1
> st_crosses(polygon, line_diff)
although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_crosses assumes that they are
planar
Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 1, where the predicate
was `crosses'
 1: (empty)
```

All this is part of the DE9IM spatial predicate logic scheme spelled out here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM

Comment: I did not know about all spatial objects, even linestrings, having an interior, a boundary, and an exterior. This is very useful for understanding why the objects still intersect after using ```st_difference()```. Is there a way, then, to clip the line so that the new boundary (end point) of the line does not touch the boundary of the polygon? I suppose that one could get the last point of the line that results from ```st_difference()```, and then remove it. Or is there a better way?

Comment: I don't think you can do that because space is a continuum and linear features (including polygon boundaries) have zero-width. You would have to shorten the line by a finite amount to stop them intersecting. Maybe buffer the polygon by a small amount and difference to that instead of the polygon? Or use `st_crosses` ? It depends on why you are doing this really...

Comment: I have two neighboring polygons, and I am trying to extract the parts of linestrings (all of which intersect a single linestring for the border between the polygons) that fall only in one polygon or the other. Your buffering idea essentially gets me to where I need; I lose a tiny bit of information about the linestrings' end parts, but it usefully returns only the parts of linestrings in either one polygon or the other. Last thing: do you happen to know the smallest possible value to give the ```dist``` argument of ```st_buffer``` (unit is meters)? I cannot find this in the Github source code.

Comment: Hard to say really, will depend on how the maths is done in the code, but R keeps some values related to precision in the `.Machine` object, so try `.Machine$double.eps` which on my machine is the order of 10^-16

Comment: Great, this all helps.